# how to get the html format data in json in objective-c

Tags: html, ios, json

The HTML data contains multiple lines with different anchor tags. The body on JSON like below format:

```
"description": "<div><b>Hiiiiiii,</b> officially known as <b>Hiiiiiii,</b>
```

Comment: this thml data cintais<div><b>   </b>

Comment: It's unclear to me what the question is. You want to create JSON? Then you'd use `NSJSONSerialization` method `dataForJSONObject`. Please clarify what the question is and show us what you tried.

Comment: no, i want get html data fromat from json

Answer (score 0):

Well you need this method to strip down the HTML tags from the string.

First you get the whole string in a variable like `NSSting *wholeHtml = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];`.

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString {
  NSRange r;
  NSString *toReturn;
  while ((r = [inputString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
  toReturn = [inputString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return toReturn;
 }
```

Then you call this method like this : `NSString *outputString = [self stringByStrippingHTML:wholeHtml];` and you will get the required string in the variable `outputString`. You can also create a catagory of NSString and that would make your work more easy.

Answer (score 0):

1 Take a string and store JSON key's description value in it .
 eg: NSString *str=[JSON value for key :@"description"];
2 Now Take a WebView and give this string to it .
eg:UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
  [webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];